# Django template ifequal comparison of decimals

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So, I have a decimalfield that can be 3 different values. In my view,
I pass in a dictionary of values that contains the appropriate decimal
values as keys.

```
{% for item in booklist %}  
    {% for key, value in numvec.items %}  
        {{item.number}}  
        {% ifequals item.number {{key}} %}  
            {{value}}  
        {% endifequals %}  
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

this is the dict I pass in as numvec:

```
numvec = {"TEST":Decimal("0.999"), "TEST2":Decimal("0.500"),
```

"TEST3":Decimal("0.255")}

the number field was defined as having these choices in my model:

```
BOOK_CHOICES=((Decimal("0.999"), 'TEST'),(Decimal("0.500"), 'TEST2'),(Decimal("0.255"), 'TEST3'),)
```

The item number prints out just fine in the view if I compare the dict
with the attribute, but for some reason the ifequals cannot properly
compare two decimals together. Is this a bug, or am I doing something
wrong in my template with ifequals?

Comment: This might be a bug. But OTOH decimals are a terrible choice for keys. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+decimal

Comment: Also I couldn't figure out what you are trying to accomplish with that template. Could you elaborate more on the example. Also please indent your code snipplet to have it highlighted appropriately. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So, in my example, numvec is a value that is used in some numeric calculation. When presenting a book report, I want to show "TEST", "TEST2", etc, in the template instead of the raw decimal value, as this has more value to a human reading the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal), it seems you can only compare strings. I'd make my own [template tag](http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/view/custom-template-tags-in-django/) if I were you.

Comment: Are you sure? It says "It is only possible to compare an argument to **template variables** or strings.", my emphasis added.

Answer (score 11):

It is not a bug and **it is possible** to achieve what you're trying to do.

However, first of all few remarks about your code:

- There is no "ifequals/endifequals" operator. You either use ["ifequal/endifequal"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal) or ["if/endif"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#operator).
- Second thing. Your code `{% ifequal item.number {{key}} %}` would cause TemplateSyntaxError Exception if you leave double curly brackets inside the "ifequal" or "if" operator.

**Now the solution**:

1. Just simply use ["stringformat"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat) filter to convert your decimal values to string.
2. Skip curly brackets when you use variables inside operators.
3. Don't forget that variable inside an "if" or "ifequal" operator is always represented as a string.

Here is an *example*:

```
{% for item in decimals %}  
  {% if item|stringformat:"s" == variable %}  
    {{ variable }}
  {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i needed to compare an int and a string apparently and this was exactly what i needed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

```
{% for item in decimals %}  
  {% if item|stringformat:"s" == variable %}  
    {{ variable }}
  {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

works well for comparing a decimal (like the loop) to a string (like a passed value)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to define a method on the model which encapsulates the numeric logic and returns the human-friendly string.

Or you can write a template tag to do it, which is a lot more code, but perhaps preserves the model/view layer separation a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear if this would help Ardesco but there is [template_utils](http://code.google.com/p/django-template-utils/) which has `if_greater`, `if_greater_or_equal`, `if_less`, `if_less_or_equal` tags (among others) which solve very related cases where a plain `ifequals` isn't quite enough.

after installing just add `template_utils` do your django settings.py under `INSTALLED_APPS` and then put `{% load comparison %}` in your template

Answer (score 0):

In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point.  [>>](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

E.g. if you

```
print Decimal(3.59)
```

you get

```
3.589999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
```

So if you compare two decimals in django template, better to use the answer that @Oleg Sakharov has, or alternatively you can use same method but different formatting string like:

```
if item|stringformat:".2f" == "3.59"
```